# JavaDB error 'Schema 'ROOT' does not exist'

Tags: glassfish, javadb

I am new to Java Server Faces and JavaDB. I am struggling to connect due to my database due to an error stating "Schema 'ROOT' does not exist". I'm pulling my hair out over this and I know it must be something simple. I did not set a username or password for the database "guest_book". The database exists under the APP schema. The managed bean is coded as follows..

```
    package com.jsf;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

/**
 *
 * @author pctdeveloper7
 */
@ManagedBean(name="guestbean")
@SessionScoped
public class GuestBookBean {

private String date;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String email;
private String message;

@Resource( name="jdbc/guest_book" )
DataSource ds;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of NewJSFManagedBean
 */
public GuestBookBean() {

}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}



//return a resultset of entries
public ResultSet getEntries() throws SQLException{
    //Check if was injected by the server
    if(ds == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain datsource");

    //get connection from datapool
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection("root","root");

    //check if connection was successful
    if(conn==null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");



    try{

        //Create a prepared statement to insert a new address book entry
        PreparedStatement getMessages = conn.prepareStatement("Select * " +
                "FROM MESSAGES ORDER BY lname, fname");
        CachedRowSet rowset= new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowset.populate(getMessages.executeQuery());
        return rowset;
    } finally{
        conn.close(); //return connection to pool
    }
}//End getEntries

//Save a new guestbook message
public String save() throws SQLException{

    //Check if was injected by the server
    if(ds == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain datsource");

    //get connection from datapool
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    //check if connection was successful
    if(conn==null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");

    try{
        //create a preparedStatement to insert a new guestbook entry
        PreparedStatement insertEntry = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO"+
                "messages values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        //define prepared statements arguements
        insertEntry.setString(1, fname);
        insertEntry.setString(2, lname);
        insertEntry.setString(3, email);
        insertEntry.setString(4, message);
        insertEntry.setString(5, date);

        insertEntry.executeUpdate();// insert the new entry
        return "index"; //go back to the index page

    }finally{
        conn.close();//return connection to the pool
    }
}//END Save()
```

}

The SQL used to create the database is as follows..

```
    create table messages
(
    fname varchar(25),
    lname varchar(35),
    email varchar(50),
    message varchar(300),
    "DATE" varchar(11)
);

Insert into messages
values('Jared', 'Rainey', 'jared.rainey.it@gmail.com', 'Hi!', '10-12-1982');
```

The connection pool is named GuestBookPool and the datasource is jdbc/guest_book. I didn't set passwords or username for anything and it was all created under the APP schema from what I understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is your datasource configured?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@ManagedBean(name="guestbean");`
try `@ManagedBean(name="guestbean", schema="APP");` or whatever your schema is.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JSF you can connect the to the database by creating an ApplicationContext in your Web-INF folder shown in project.

Create a singleton bean of you desired datasource.

The method that you are using is not a preferred one.

By the way, to help you more, may I ask which database you are using? Oracle, postgres, Access etc.?

Comment: It is not advisable to declare the datasource in the bean class.

Comment: As stated in the question title, the OP is using JavaDB.